# iText 5: Create a single PDF "ByteArrayOutputStream()" from two streams in a Java "HttpServlet" servlet to display in browser window

Tags: java, pdf, servlets, merge, itext

I have a Java "HttpServlet" class that creates an iText 5 PDF document by calling a Java class that returns the PDF document as a "ByteArrayOuputStream." The stream gets written to the "HttpServletResponse" of the servlet and displayed in the browser window.

In the Java servlet:

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
throws ServletException, IOException{

// Other code.

ByteArrayOutputStream baosPDF = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

// Java class call to create PDF document.

baosPDF = new InvoicePDF();

// Set up the return HTTP header.

response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=30");
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=INV_"
                            + request.getParameter("invoiceNumber").toString()
                            + ".pdf");

// Set length HTTP header value.

response.setContentLength(baosPDF.size());

// Write all data to the browser.

ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();

baosPDF.writeTo(sos);
           
sos.flush();
 
// Other code.

}
```

The above code works well.

In certain circumstances, I need to create another "ByteArrayOuputStream" PDF document in the servlet using another Java class and have that PDF document displayed first and then the other PDF document next in the browser window.

I tried concatenating the two "ByteArrayOutputStream" (write method) into one and writing to the "ServletOutputStream," but only the stream written on the end of the "ByteArrayOuputStream" displays in the browser window.

In the servlet, I need to create a single PDF "ByteArrayOuputStream," somehow merging the two PDF documents.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baosPDF = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

ByteArrayOutputStream baosCoverPDF = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

//Java class call to create PDF document

baosCoverPDF = new coverPDF();

baosPDF = new InvoicePDF(hosturl, invoiceNumber);
```

I need a single "ByteArrayOuputStream" that contains both "baoCoverPDF" and "baosPDF" streams as a single PDF that will display both PDF streams in the browser? Any help on a direction such as a combination of a "PdfReader" and "PdfCopy"?

Comment: So you are trying two concatenate two PDF documents? E.g. the first document has 3 pages, the second as 5 pages and the concatenated document thus has 8 pages?

Comment: The document that needs to display first is a cover page, only one page. The second to display consists of an invoice that may be many, up to 10 pages. Therefore, I need the cover page PDF first and then the invoice PDF. Yes, 1 page + 10, 11 pages total.

Comment: PDF documents have a complex structure incl. an index of all pages and shared resources. So concatenating two documents isn't trivial. However, iText 5 can do the heavy lifting for you. Search for "itext 5 pdfcopy example".

Comment: You want to merge two documents. Have you considered looking for answers on merging PDFs with iText?

Comment: I have searched for that exact phrase. The issue becomes that the Java servlet class has no knowledge of iText or the PDF documents that were created in its calls to the classes that use iText to make the returned output streams. It only knows about "ByteArrayOutputStream" streams. In the servlet, can it be possible to create iText documents from the two returned "ByteArrayOutputStream," streams, merge the documents, and convert that document back to a"ByteArrayOutputStream" to write to the "ServletOutputStream "?

Comment: Your solution in your answer is approximately what I had in mind when asking you to look for *merging PDFs with iText*.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work inside the Java servlet with the following code.

```
Document pdfDocument = new Document();
ByteArrayOutputStream pdfOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(pdfDocument, pdfOutputStream);

pdfDocument.open();

baosCoverPDF = new coverPDF();

PdfReader coverPageReader = new PdfReader(baosCoverPDF.toByteArray());

for (int i = 1; i <= coverPageReader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
   copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(coverPageReader, i));
}

baosInvoice = new InvoicePDF(); 

PdfReader invoiceReader = new PdfReader(baosInvoice.toByteArray());

for (int i = 1; i <= invoiceReader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
   copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(invoiceReader, i));
}

pdfDocument.close();

baosPDF.write(pdfOutputStream.toByteArray());

copy.close();
coverPageReader.close();
invoiceReader.close();
```

I then perform the rest as before to output to the browser window.

```
// Set up the return HTTP header.

response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=30");
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=INV_"
                            + 
request.getParameter("invoiceNumber").toString()
                            + ".pdf");

// Set length HTTP header value.

response.setContentLength(baosPDF.size());

// Write all data to the browser.

ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();

baosPDF.writeTo(sos);
           
sos.flush();
```